# How to loop NATS messages received over channel

Tags: go, nats.io

I have a code like that:

```golang
package main


import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)

func main()  {
    nc, _ := nats.Connect(nats.DefaultURL)
    for {
        nc.Subscribe("request", func(m *nats.Msg) {
            fmt.Printf("Received a message: %s\n", string(m.Data))
            m.Respond([]byte("Received"))
        })
    }
}
```

What I try to do is receive a message and after receiving a message send a reply to message, forever as shown in the example.

However with the code above, there are some problems. When I added `for {`to the code, it repeats the same message until a new message is received.

What is the correct implementation to receive messages continuously with NATS? (Without replying received messages)

Comment: Your `for` loop is adding an infinite number of subscriptions. Just add one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you would be ended up with an unlimited subscription to the subject. You only need to call the Subscribe method once.

Firstly, the method Subscribe is returning something and we should save the value from the `Subscribe(...)` method.

```golang
s, err := nc.Subscribe(subj, msgHandler)
// handle err
for {
 // if something happened, quit the loop
}
s.Unsubscribe()
```

The `msgHandle` will be called when there are new messages on the `subj`. So you just have to wait. And you could be waiting with infinite loop after creating a subscription.

However, I think it is better to do a subscription using a channel.

```
// Channel Subscriber
ch := make(chan *nats.Msg, 64)
sub, err := nc.ChanSubscribe("foo", ch)
// handle err
for msg := range ch {
    // do something to the nats.Msg object
}
// Unsubscribe if needed
sub.Unsubscribe()
close(ch)
```

Please consider reading the documentation [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/nats-io/go-nats).