# How do I make NATS continuously listen for messages?

Tags: node.js, nats.io

If I use the following code NATS listens and processes the first message but not new messages after that. How do I make the sub not close and continuously process messages?

The code below is from the NATS sample code I'm testing with. In can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nats/v/2.15.1) in the fist example under "Publish and Subscribe".

What happens is if I add an `async` fn just before the `console.log` to process the message then the for loop exists and does not process any more messages. If I don't to this, it continuously processes new messages and the `console.log` never prints. How can I make a call inside the loop and not exist?

```js
(async () => {
  for await (const m of sub) {
    console.log(`[${sub.getProcessed()}]: ${sc.decode(m.data)}`);
  }
  console.log("subscription closed");
})();
```

Comment: Please show more relevant code that shows what module you are importing, shows what `sub` is.  Shows any relevant initialization code.  So far, you seem to be assuming we know more than we do about what this is doing or is supposed to do.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647226/how-to-loop-nats-messages-received-over-channel?rq=2

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm just looking at the example code for the module and testing it. It can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nats/v/2.15.1), the fist example under "Publish and Subscribe". I'm thinking some sort of `while (true)` but that seems old-skool. Event handling seems better.

Comment: Please edit your question to add that info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the entire code (connection, subscription, etc), what I can imagine is that you are not passing the subscription as a parameter to your anonymous function.

Look at this working example:

```
async function connectAndListen() {
        const nc = await connect({ servers: 'nats://localhost:4222' });
        const sc = StringCodec();
        const subscription = nc.subscribe('subject');

        (async (sub) => {

            console.log(`listening for ${sub.getSubject()} requests...`);

            for await (const m of sub) {
                console.log(sc.decode(m.data))
            }
            
            console.log(`subscription ${sub.getSubject()} drained.`);
        })(subscription);
}

connectAndListen();
```

On the example, the anonymous function receives `sub` parameter (the subscription), and at the end of the function declaration, we are calling itself passing `subscription` as the `sub` parameter.